# Fake active directory response from a request of a web application

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap

I have a web application done in .NET that with an API requests the employee info from the company Active Directory, I need to fake the information that Active Directory gives back for testing purposes.

This is the connection string it uses to access active directory

```
<LDAP OU="Employees" DC1="company" server="DC02" userName="ldap" password="P@ssw0rd!" />
```

This is the code for retrieving an specific user, I would like to be 
able to fake the response so it can retrieves what ever I want.

```
public LdapUser FindUser(string username)
    {
        LdapUser user;
        _config.AddMapping(new LdapUserMap(_ldapConfiguration));
        using (var context = new DirectoryContext(_config))
        {
            user = context.Query<LdapUser>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.SAmAccountName == username) ??
                   context.Query<LdapUser>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Mail == username + "@" + _ldapConfiguration.EmailDC);

        }
        return user;
    }
```

Is there a way to do this without modifying the code and running the application normally?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to run your own LDAP server. You can try [GLAuth](https://github.com/glauth/glauth). I've never used it, but I found it by searching for "lightweight LDAP server". It seems to be made for just this purpose.

However, Active Directory does have its own quirks sometimes, so you might run into weird issues depending on what you're doing.

Active Directory itself can be installed on any Windows Server installation. If you have a Windows Server, you could install AD on it for your own testing.

Once you get something setup, you can change you configuration to connect to that instead of your organization's AD.